# Calling the forward method in PyTorch vs. calling the model instance

Tags: python, class, oop, pytorch

A lot of the PyTorch tutorials I've been viewing do something like this.

Define model:

```
class Network(nn.Module):
    def __init__():
        super().__init__()
        self.conv1 = ..
        ... 
    
    def forward(x)
        ...
    ...
```

Once the Network has been instantiated (`net = Network()`), the people in the tutorials write `net(input_data)` instead of `net.forward(input_data)`.
I tried `net.forward()` and it gives the same results as `net()`.

Why is this a common practice, and also why does this work?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You should avoid calling `Module.forward`.
The difference is that all the hooks are dispatched in the `__call__` function [see this](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/_modules/torch/nn/modules/module.html#Module), so if you call `.forward` and have hooks in your model, the hooks won’t have any effect.

Inshort when you call `Module.forward`, pytorch hooks wont have any effect

Detailed answer can be found in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55338756/why-there-are-different-output-between-model-forwardinput-and-modelinput)  post