# calling function inside class

Tags: python, pytorch

For the code below: Can someone explain, how the forward function is called in "y_pred = model(X_train)", even model(X_train) does not specifiy which function it should use? Is it because the forward function is the only function in the model class?

```py
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import numpy as np
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

# 0) Prepare data
bc = datasets.load_breast_cancer()
X, y = bc.data, bc.target

n_samples, n_features = X.shape

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=1234)

# scale
sc = StandardScaler()
X_train = sc.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test = sc.transform(X_test)

X_train = torch.from_numpy(X_train.astype(np.float32))
X_test = torch.from_numpy(X_test.astype(np.float32))
y_train = torch.from_numpy(y_train.astype(np.float32))
y_test = torch.from_numpy(y_test.astype(np.float32))

y_train = y_train.view(y_train.shape[0], 1)
y_test = y_test.view(y_test.shape[0], 1)

# 1) Model
# Linear model f = wx + b , sigmoid at the end
class Model(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, n_input_features):
        super(Model, self).__init__()
        self.linear = nn.Linear(n_input_features, 1)

    def forward(self, x):
        y_pred = torch.sigmoid(self.linear(x))
        return y_pred

model = Model(n_features)

# 2) Loss and optimizer
num_epochs = 100
learning_rate = 0.01
criterion = nn.BCELoss()
optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=learning_rate)

# 3) Training loop
for epoch in range(num_epochs):
    # Forward pass and loss
    y_pred = model(X_train)
    loss = criterion(y_pred, y_train)

    # Backward pass and update
    loss.backward()
    optimizer.step()

    # zero grad before new step
    optimizer.zero_grad()

    if (epoch+1) % 10 == 0:
        print(f'epoch: {epoch+1}, loss = {loss.item():.4f}')


with torch.no_grad():
    y_predicted = model(X_test)
    y_predicted_cls = y_predicted.round()
    acc = y_predicted_cls.eq(y_test).sum() / float(y_test.shape[0])
    print(f'accuracy: {acc.item():.4f}')
```

source:https://github.com/patrickloeber/pytorchTutorial/blob/69637721ed9fa2ccf81a1093a928a52bbb591439/08_logistic_regression.py#L31

Comment: It because the base class might have defined a method [`__call__`](https://medium.com/@johnidouglasmarangon/using-call-method-to-invoke-class-instance-as-a-function-f61396145567).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

User @Jorge is correct. I want to add a bit of context here.

- If you look at the [source code](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/397fb2762ef018684f2223fda6a8e64922b77649/torch/nn/modules/module.py#L1575), `__call__` eventually calls `forward()`.
- However, based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66594136/calling-the-forward-method-in-pytorch-vs-calling-the-model-instance), [this](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/is-model-forward-x-the-same-as-model-call-x/33460/3), and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55338756/why-there-are-different-output-between-model-forwardinput-and-modelinput) `model(data)` and `model.forward(data)` are not the same, and it is recommended to use `model(data)`.

Answer (score 1):

This should help https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Module.html.
This is what is said about forwards:

```
forward(*input):
    Defines the computation performed at every call.
    Should be overridden by all subclasses.
```

This type of behavioure is common when you overwrite a class (`class Model(nn.Module)` in this case). Read up on overwritting it should help!

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question.